Cast function pointer to void* in function invocation then recast them to original type
I have a struct that contains a function callback that's being defined differently depending on the compiler
typedef struct structA
{
#ifdef _compilerA_
  void (*func) (int);
  int param;
#else
  void (func) (unionA);
  unionA param;
#endif
}

and the unionA is defined as
typedef union unionA
{
  int num;
}

now I have an interface that originally take a void(*fp)(int), and then a local function pointer will be set to fp, but due to the different types of fp that depends on the compiler, I have to set it as follow
void interfaceB(void *fp, int param)
{
  structA local;
#ifdef _compilerA_
  local->func = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int)>(fp);
  local->param = param;
#else
  local->func = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(unionA)>(fp);
  unionA param_unionA;
  param_unionA.num = param;
  local->param = param_unionA;
}

The issue arise when I'm passing function callback to function A and trying to cast it to void*. Let's say I have a function callback
void callbackC (int param)

and when I try to cast it to void* to interfaceB I ran into a compiler issue
interfaceB(reinterpret_cast<void*>(callbackC)

The error message was error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)(int)’[-fpermissive]. How would I fix this issue? Thank you.

Pointers to functions can't be converted to or from void*. It's one of the things C++ inherited from C. A simple way to solve your problem is through std::function. Use proper type-aliases and almost never use void*.

And in the future when asking questions related to build errors, please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log.

On a different note, you don't need typedef for structures or unions in C++. The structure or union tag name is a type name as well.

@Someprogrammerdude "Pointers to functions can't be converted to or from void"* They can't be implicitly converted, but a cast should work. (I know the standard doesn't guarantee it to work, but every modern platform seems to support it.)

I can't reproduce, reinterpret_cast works here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4zMxsrM17

On another note, I think you should take some time to think about your design. Your solution could very likely be rewritten in a more C++ way, without the need for the conditional compilation and pointers.

Anytime I see void* in C++ my first reaction is "do you really want to do that?". In general raw pointers are already a bad idea, and void* double so.  Then I also see you use union which probable doesn't behave in C++ as you expect (it is much more complex than in "C").  For C++ you should look at std::function or some more generic template approach. (And in generic code you could use void* but only if you  know what type-erasure is all about).

@HolyBlackCat I was working with GCC 9.x.x version, I know that in the earlier versions, GCC is less strict in these type checking issues

A lot of C APIs provide callback mechanisms using either void* or uintptr_t. So this is necessary sometimes.

There's nothing to be "less strict" about, your code is legal and compiles (even in GCC 9.x: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/esMMMjqzz). If it doesn't compile for you, please tell the exact compiler version and the flags you use.

related: Why are function pointers and data pointers incompatible in C/C++?

void (func) (unionA); is not a function pointer, it is a member function.

@HolyBlackCat I edited my post to show the exact error message, I don't know why it works on your example but mine is similar and does not work

The message sounds like you didn't use the cast, and just tried an implicit conversion. Please read about [mcve].

Why don't you move the type definition up and redefine the argument type depending on the compiler?
#ifdef _compilerA_
typedef int FuncArg;
inline FuncArg funcArgFromInt(int const x) { return x; }
#else
typedef unionA FuncArg;
inline FuncArg funcArgFromInt(int const x) {
  unionA param_unionA;
  param_unionA.num = x;
  return param_unionA;
}
#endif
typedef void (*FuncPtr)(FuncArg);

struct StructA {
  FuncPtr func;
  FuncArg arg;
};

Then the call just becomes:
void interfaceB(FuncPtr const fp, int const param) {
  StructA const local{fp, param};
  // do things with `local`, presumably? E.g.:
  local.fp(funcArgFromInt(local.arg));
}

